# XMLHttpRequsest failing despite CORS permissions

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors

So - if I visit a URL at my remote server via my browser, example.host.com, I get some JSON back - great.

If I put that exact same URL into some javascript that makes a XMLHttpRequest from a page being served from a server on my local machine, I get nothing, with a `status=0` and a `statusText=null`.  Pertinent facts:

- The remote server's response header has `access-control-allow-origin: '*'`
- When I make the XMLHttpRequest, it adds `referer: "http://localhost:2154/HV"` and `origin: "http://localhost:2154"` to its request header.  These of course weren't there when I just put the URL into my browser.
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#XMLHttpRequests_being_stopped) says the status reporting I described above usually happens when a request is unsent.
- I've built my local server with node + express
- The code for my XHR is as follows:

  ```
  function fetchit(host, n){
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

          if(this.readyState == 4){
              //do cool stuff
          }

      }
      xmlhttp.withCredentials = true;
      xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://'+host+'/?cmd=getMsg&n='+n);
      xmlhttp.send();
  }
  ```

I get the impression that this has something to do with the `origin` that XHR is sticking on the request header, but I thought the line I mentioned in the response header would make `origin` not matter.  Clearly there is something I don't understand about CORS - thanks in advance for any ideas,

Answer (score 0):

Alright - I figured this out.  The problem is that credentialed requests are a bigger pain in the butt than non-credentialed requests.  [This MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials) explains what needed to happen.  TL;DR:

- The browser will not expose the response text of a credentialed request if the response header doesn't have `access-control-allow-credentials: true`
- `access-control-allow-origin` can't be wildcarded in credentialed requests.